# PyArrow: Writing a parquet file with a particular schema

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

For testing purposes, I am trying to generate a file with dummy data, but with the following schema (schema of the real data):

```
pa.schema([
  pa.field('field1', pa.int64()),
  pa.field('field2', pa.list_(pa.field('element', pa.int64()))),
  pa.field('field3', pa.list_(pa.field('element', pa.float64()))),
  pa.field('field4', pa.list_(pa.field('element', pa.float64()))),
], )
```

I have the following code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

loc = "test.parquet"

data = {
        "field1": [0],
        "field2": [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
        "field3": [[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9]],
        "field4": [[2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9]]
    }

schema1 = pa.schema([
    pa.field('field1', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('field2', pa.list_(pa.field('element', pa.int64()))),
    pa.field('field3', pa.list_(pa.field('element', pa.float64()))),
    pa.field('field4', pa.list_(pa.field('element', pa.float64()))),
], )

schema2 = pa.schema([
    pa.field('field1', pa.int64()),
    pa.field('field2', pa.list_(pa.int64())),
    pa.field('field3', pa.list_(pa.float64())),
    pa.field('field4', pa.list_(pa.float64())),
], )

writer = pq.ParquetWriter(loc, schema1)
writer.write(pa.table(data))
writer.close()
```

The dictionary in the code, when converted to a PyArrow table and written to a parquet file, generates a file whose schema matches `schema2`. Passing `schema1` to the writer gives an error. How can I change the dictionary in such a way that its schema matches `schema1` when converted to a table?

Answer (score 2):

Semantically the schemas are the same, the name of the list item ("element") should not matter. This used to be an issue but has been fixed in pyarrow 11.0.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14999)

So you can upgrade to pyarrow and it should work.

Alternatively you can make sure your table has got the correct schema by doing either:

```
writer.write(pa.table(data, schema=schema1))
```

Or casting by casting it:

```
writer.write(pa.table(data).cast(schema1))
```